# Scroll vis.js timeline vertically on item drag

Tags: scroll, drag, timeline, vis.js

Is there any way to make the vis.js timeline scroll vertically when dragging an item? With a fixed height and a lot of groups out of view, if one needs to move an item to a different group, he needs to drag it down a couple of groups, let go, scroll or drag the timeline manually a bit, to then re-grab the item and continue dragging. I would like to just drag the item and have the timeline scroll automatically while I do that. I haven't found any combination of options to get there. Does anyone have some suggestions please? Thanks a lot for your help.